# How can I change the color of text which is displayed in a text box after a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, textbox, textcolor

On my **C# code** when the compile button is pressed, it displays a Success message in a text box but i want different lines of the text to be different colors. How can I do that? I'm using **.NET Framework 4.7.2** The textbox used is a "RichTextBox"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcbHs.png)

> ```
> CompileLogTB.Text = CompileLogTB.Text + Environment.NewLine + "[+]Successfully compiled file!" + Environment.NewLine + "[+]Task has been completed." + Environment.NewLine + "[+]You may now check the folder" + Environment.NewLine +  "this application is located for the output." + Environment.NewLine + "Comipled In 34ms!";
> ```

return;

Comment: You forgot to mention what framework your UI is based on. Remove useless tags, as `[text]` and `[color]` and add one that specifies that (very important) detail

Comment: What kind of control in which framework is visualizing the text? A simple _textBox_ can't do that. You need some control that can handle such kind of format information like RTF or HTML.

Comment: Not possible with a plain text box. You need to use something else.

Comment: Yes it is using A (RichTextBox) and Framework .NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red; //color what you want.
```